# SQL Server - Query Each Group of a Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C, 
  CASE
    WHEN 1 = (
               SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT D) 
               FROM MyTable tbl2
               WHERE tbl2.A = tbl.A AND tbl2.B = tbl.B and tbl2.C = tbl.C
             )
      THEN (
             SELECT AVG(D)
             FROM MyTable tbl3
             WHERE tbl3.A = tbl.A AND tbl3.B = tbl.B and tbl3.C = tbl.C
           )
    ELSE SUM(D)
FROM MyTable tbl
GROUP BY A, B, C
```

Does anyone know of a better way to write this query?

What I'd really like, instead of re-querying the table twice, is to query each group of the group by in the select statement. Is that even possible?

I'm guessing it's possible to do a JOIN of sorts, but if I would strongly prefer to query each group of original rows that are being aggregated together (to form the group).

I'm running on SQL Server 2005.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:  2011-11-09**

In light of some of the questions, I think I didn't explain my goals clearly enough. I hope this edit serves as a better example:

My question is this: When I do a group by, is there a way of querying the rows in the table that comprise of each group in the select statement? Is there some SQL keyword/function? Here’s what I mean:

```
 Table:
| Code | Qty  | ColumnA | ColumnB |
| A    | 100  | 3       | 100     |
| A    | 100  | 4       | 200     |
| A    | 0    | 0       | 300     |
| B    | 0    | 0       | 400     |
| B    |100   | 1       | 500     |

SELECT Code, SUM(ColumnB), 
  (SELECT AVG(ColumnA) FROM Table WHERE Code = tbl.Code AND Qty <> 0) AS ColumnA
FROM Table tbl
GROUP BY Code
```

The output I’m looking for is:

```
| Code | ColumnA | ColumnB |
| A    | 3.5     | 600     |
| B    | 1       | 900     |
```

As you can see, I’d like to avoid that nested query by querying the 3 rows in the Table that group of A of comprised of. Do you know of a SQL keyword or function that gives me the original rows of each group? Or perhaps a better way to write the query?

Comment: Is there a reason that you "strongly" prefer one particular solution to your problem as opposed to just wanting the solution that works best?

Comment: So when there's 1 you want the avg else you want the sum?  Why not just SUM?

Comment: @Dan - thats not quite right, when there is one distinct value ( records where D=5 for example) the OP is taking the average (5) instead of the sum (50). Not that it makes much sense mathematically, but thats the OPs logic in the post

Comment: @Andrew The OP could just use `SUM(DISTINCT D)` and be done with it. Yes, it wouldn't replicate precisely what the OP was asking for, but I question whether the OP actually knows what (s)he's asking for.

Comment: @Tom H: The reason I used the word 'strongly' is that this example is quite simple from my real task. Also, there are other instances where I need to query the original rows composing of the group, so that's why I want to lean that way. But to your point, a solution is just that; a solution and I'll take anything that works, but I do have my preferences. Thanks!

Comment: @ean - SUM(DISTINCT D) wouldn't give the same results though - I agree the logic is 'strange' that is being requested.

Comment: Just wanted to add some more context to the example (which I think will help understanding it). The table I'm querying off of, MyTable in this case, is a cumulative listing of widgets. Each widget obviously has many attributes, like code, description, currency purchased in, quantity purchases, is order active, etc, etc. When I'm doing the group by, each "group" contains all data pertaining to each widget (each code/description). However, for some of the output columns in the query, I need to query only off the active widgets; other columns need to query off active/inactive widgets.

Comment: @pdalbe01:  Why do you want the AVG of one item?

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to do.  Why do you need to query for specific columns based on active/inactive?  I don't think you can access the groups the results came from.  They are combined at into a single result set... the individual rows don't really exist to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you simply want:

```
SELECT Code
     , AVG(CASE WHEN ColumnA<>0 THEN ColumnA ELSE NULL END) AS ColumnA
     , SUM(ColumnB) AS ColumnB
FROM Table tbl
GROUP BY Code
```